# Ant Design Form Label Ellipsis not working properly

Tags: reactjs, antd

Does anyone know how to add ellipsis in the antd form labels and set it dynamic ?

Here's my Form Code

```
  <Form
      form={form}
      labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
      wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
        <Col span={8}>
          <Form.Item
            name="Placeholder input"
            label={
              <Typography.Text ellipsis={{ tooltip: "Placeholder input }} >
                Placeholder input
              </Typography.Text>
          }
          >
            <Select placeholder="Search by Type" notFoundContent={null} />
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
    </Form>
```

Ellipsis for text label are not working properly. It's showing like this

[image]

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Aside from your missing double-quote in your ellipsis prop, your code seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-17-0-alpha-0-forked-tc5q8?file=/index.js